# Showing that $Y^c$ is dense in $X$, if $ Y \subset (X, \| \cdot \|)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**Exercise :**

> Let $X$ be a normed space $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ and $Y$ be a proper subspace of $X$, $Y \subset X$. Show that the complement set $Y^c$ is dense in $X$.

**Question :**

I'm totally at loss on how to start this exercise.

I know that a normed space means it's a linear space carrying the definition and properties of the norm, while on the other hand, a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called dense (in $X$) if every point $x$ in $X$ either belongs to $A$ or is a limit point of $A$; that is, the closure of $A$ is constituting the whole set $X$.

**But how would I proceed to showing rigorously the statement of the exercise ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in X$ but $a\notin Y$. Let $y\in Y$. Then $y+ta\in Y^c$ for $t\ne 0$.
Now let $t\to0$.

Comment: Then for $t \to 0$,  $y + ta$ would be a "point" lying on the bounds of $Y^c$, thus a limit point and thus $Y^c$ is dense in $X$ ?

Comment: How are we sure that $y+ta \in Y^c$ for $t \neq 0$ ?

Comment: @Rebellos When you say $Y$ is a "subspace", you do mean it's a vector subspace, right? That is, $Y$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication etc.?

Comment: Yes, a vector subspace. I just can't comprehend about how we are sure that an operation of a falls into the complement.

Comment: For $y\in Y$, $a\not\in Y$ and $t\neq 0$, the vector $z=y+ta$ does not belong to $Y$ because $a= \frac 1t (z-y)$.